# There is no row at position 0 for inserting data in database

Tags: c#, database, runtime-error, row

i am facing a similar problem and i dont know how to solve them i tried many things but this issue i can't solve yet please help 
actually problem is i want to select value from database and if ds == null so textbox value i want to insert in database but when i insert it's shown me error
here is the code :

```
string query = "Select * From Contacts where [Phone No] = " + textBox00.Text + "";
                    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
                    {
                        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                            if (ds != null)
                            {
                                adapter.Fill(ds);
                                label128.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
                                setaluefortext00001 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Phone No"].ToString();
                                setaluefortext00002 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Address"].ToString();
                                conn.Close();   
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                adapter.Fill(ds);
                                connection.Open();
                                OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand();
                                command1.Connection = connection;
                                command1.CommandText = "insert into Contacts ([Name],[Phone No],[Address])values('" + textBox.Text + "'," + textBox00.Text + ",'" + textBox000.Text + "');";
                                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                connection.Close();
                                label128.Text = textBox.Text;
                                setaluefortext00002 = textBox00.Text;
                                setaluefortext00003 = textBox000.Text;
                            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your return database: **table has no any row**.

Please also put validation for row count as below:

```
if (ds != null && ds.tables[0].rows.count>0)
```

Because in your code ds never null as you assign new dataset :  `DataSet ds = new DataSet();`

So always if statement execute, code not reach to else statement

You can also put your **`adapter.Fill(ds);`** in the above if statement

```
string query = "Select * From Contacts where [Phone No] = " + textBox00.Text + "";
                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
                {
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        adapter.Fill(ds);
                        if (ds != null && ds.Tables[0].rows.count>0)
                        {                                
                            label128.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
                            setaluefortext00001 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Phone No"].ToString();
                            setaluefortext00002 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Address"].ToString();

                        }
                        else
                        {                                

                            OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand();
                            command1.Connection = conn ;
                            command1.CommandText = "insert into Contacts ([Name],[Phone No],[Address])values('" + textBox.Text + "'," + textBox00.Text + ",'" + textBox000.Text + "');";
                            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();                                
                            label128.Text = textBox.Text;
                            setaluefortext00002 = textBox00.Text;
                            setaluefortext00003 = textBox000.Text;
                        }
                        conn.Close();
```

Comment: now it's shown cannot find table[0]

Comment: sorry it should be Tables[0], "T" in uppercase, have you tried it?

Comment: yea i am using T in upper case but now it's working fine